# Drupal 7 Clean URLs won't enable

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, clean-urls

On my installation the checkbox is visible to enable clean URLs.

When you check it and click Save, it reloads the page with the checkbox no longer checked. Why is this?

FYI you can access the page using the clean URL version: /admin/config/search/clean-urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run through this guide to ensure you did every step:

https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Make sure AllowOverride All is set in your vhost config. Double check that all of step 3 is set in your config file correctly. I had a similar issue on one of my servers and running through this guide fixed my problem.

Comment: In my case (using WAMP) I had to enable rewrite_module under "Apache modules" menu. Going through the guide made me aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. After several hours I saw the

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['clean_url'] = 0;
```

at the end of settings.php.
For turning Clean URLs on it should be

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['clean_url'] = 1;
```

or even remove this line at all.

Hope it helps somebody ;).

Answer (score 0):

In my **settings.php** I changed:

```
$conf['clean_url'] = 0;
```

to:

```
$conf['clean_url'] = 1;
```